# How can I provide Q:\Temp\yw\ostn02-ntv2-data\OSTN02_NTv2.gsb?

Tags: qgis

On opening geopackage I get `This transformation requires the grid file “Q:\Temp\yw\ostn02-ntv2-data\OSTN02_NTv2.gsb”, which is not available for use on the system.`

How can I provide this file?

This dataset comes from https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/housing_zones - are they again providing dataset referencing internal servers/files?

I found https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/format that seems to provide matching files but QGIS is not able to open this files.

[image]
[image]

It turns out that file type option was expecting something else that `.gsb` file for `gsb` files.

And this filter option was placed outside screen, in way that it was quite hidden due to unlucky dialog positioning.

To fix this I needed to move dialog window to reveal that option.

Now it has a new bizarre error.

[image]

This error is really weird as I do NOT have and do NOT want to copy `Q:\Temp\yw\ostn02-ntv2-data\OSTN02_NTv2.gsb` file.

So this error makes no sense.

Comment: I ended opening dataset, setting projection to EPSG:27700 according to description in website and then processing. No idea is it inducing some error or not, but data seems to match what I expected.